# Live Updates to Javascript Plotly graph C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, plotly

I am new to Javascript, MVC, and making websites.  I am making a company internal site that is used as a  GUI for controlling hardware.  The computer (Server) is connected to another machine taking measurements (data points).  I have successfully created a page that plots this data using the plotly library, but instead of sending all of the data points from the server to the client after all the measurements have been taken, they want one point to be plotted at a time.  This means making calls back to the server for each point.  The class (object) that contains the functionality to do this is called the MeasurementManager.  My first though was to pass this class into the view by ViewBag, then call the function that takes the measurement in a loop using razor syntax.  For testing we can say we are taking 10 measurements.  Then call the Javascript function that updates the plotly plot also inside of the loop and pass the data from the MeasurementManager to the plotly update function.  I'm just not sure how to do this.  For argument sake if it is possible to call the MeasurmentManager function inside of a javascript loop, that would be fine as well.

Controller: (Just created the MeasurementManager object and checks if it was created without error.  I didn't want to do this error checking in the view with razor syntax.  I tried passing the model strictly but I couldn't figure out how to get access to the same instance of the object, so ViewBag was the way to go.  This function runs after clicking a button in another view)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Calibrate()
    {
        MeasurementManager measurementManager;
        try
        {
            measurementManager = new MeasurementManager(ref ErrorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("ErrorView");
        }
        ViewBag.MeasurementManager = measurementManager;
        return View();
```

View: (This is the Calibrate view returned from the above function. It is enough code to get a plotly plot with no points plotted, and it contains an update plot function)

```
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <div id="CalibrationPlot" style="width:100%; height:1000px" class="js-plotly-plot"></div>
        <div class="plot-container plotly"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        <script>
        // Define Layout
        var layout = {
          xaxis: {range: [0, 256], title: "Mux"},
          yaxis: {range: [0, 5*Math.pow(10, -10)], title: "Capacitance"},  
          title: "Capacitance vs Mux"
        };
        
            // Display using Plotly
            Plotly.newPlot("CalibrationPlot", data, layout);
            </script>
            
            <script>
                function updatePlot(capacitancePoint, elementPoint)
                {
                    var update = [{
                        x: elementPoint,
                        y: capacitancePoint
                    }];
                    Plotly.update("CalibrationPlot", update, 0)
                }
             </script>
```

What I would like to add to the view is something like this which will measure a point and plot that value on the plotly plot.  Hopefully this would achieve making a live plot on the webpage.

```
@{
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    double MeasuredValue = ViewBag.measurementManager.MeasureValue();  // Y Coordinate
    int xValue = i;                                                    // X Coordinate
    // Make a call to Plotly.update (updatePlot function) and pass in these two values here
}
}
```

Feel free to add any solution that you think would work.  I'm new to all of this and this is my first stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use SignalR to update the frontend graph in real-time. OR Try to Blazor maybe that helps also.